# "Facing the resignation" meaning

Tags: american-english, british-english

What does it mean: "You'll just be spending your day working to overcome strains, trying to live your life and **at various points facing the resignation** that if you can't get your *** of this wheel maybe you are never going to get to where you want in life." What means "facing the resignation"? I suppose it means accept that you can't achieve anything without hard work. Am I right?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me - *facing the **realization...***

Comment: I was reading a book and that phrase was there. So I can't quite understand what it means.

Comment: If the sense of ***resignation*** is in fact intended, it would need to be expressed as something more like *...at various points **becoming resigned to the fact** that...* But it still wouldn't be "good" English.

Comment: Okay - [I found the source.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CjwmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&dq=%22at+various+points+facing+the+resignation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_qODc9NThAhUTThUIHQYDC0oQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22at%20various%20points%20facing%20the%20resignation%22&f=false) It's not a standard English usage.

Comment: You're right. So you don't recommend to read this? I'm in process of learning English and that's bestseller book in Amazon.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend it as a "teaching aid", no! It's a curious mixture of "high formal" register and "gutter-speak", as I can see by just glancing at a page or two. And for my money the *specific* usage you're asking about is out-and-out *incorrect*, even if it's "comprehensible" (***if*** we rule out the far more likely possibility that it's a typo/malapropism).

Comment: ...continuing to nit-pick, I see he's erroneously capitalized *don't break out the **Champagne** just yet* a little further down in the text. [Here's what Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=break+out+the+champagne%2Cbreak+out+the+Champagne&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreak%20out%20the%20champagne%3B%2Cc0) says about that! :)

Comment: Okay, I got it! :) I have this book translated in my first language and find this book interesting. Maybe I'll try to read it next time. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't put you off. If you're going to read books written in a foreign language, it's probably much more important that you should choose texts you find *interesting*, rather than books that other people tell you are "well written". Everyone makes *some* mistakes with their use of language, so you may as well get used to that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be "resigned" to something means having accepted something (usually unpleasant) that you can't do anything about (see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resigned ). Resignation is the noun form of this. "Facing" means something very similar (see verb sense 2 here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/face) - that you are accepting something. "Facing the resignation" is thus a bit of a tautology - it means you are dealing with the fact that you are most likely going to have to accept the fact of something.